# Missing number, treated as zero (\maketitle)

Tags: titles, abstract

So I am working on writing my dissertation using a LaTeX template provided (without support) by the institution, but I am consistently getting an error when attempting to compile the document. The error is not catastrophic and the document compiles fine and looks correct, but I would like to learn about what is causing the error and how I might go about fixing it for the future.

The document uses a custom class file, which I have condensed as much as possible into the minimum successful compilable example:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{title_abstract}

\DeclareOption{singlespace}{
        \renewcommand{\textspace}{\relax}
}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[12pt]{report}[1994/06/01]

\def\versiontag{}                    
\def\ds@draft{
        \overfullrule 5pt 
        \def\versiontag{{\normalsize\rm - DRAFT \number\month/\number\day{} -}}
}

\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}          
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
               {\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
                 \setcounter{page}{\z@}}
               {\newpage}

\newenvironment{abstractpage}
               {\newpage}
               {\newpage}

\newcommand{\department}[1]{\gdef\@department{#1}}

\newcommand{\advisor}[1]{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}

\department{??DEPARTMENT??}
\advisor{??ADVISOR??}
\date{\number\year}

\newcommand{\@member}[1]{\begin{center}
  \raisebox{-8pt}[0pt][17pt]{\rule{2.8in}{.5pt}}\par    
  \raisebox{pt}[3pt][0pt]{#1}\par\end{center}     
  }

\newcounter{@members}           \newcommand{\@membera}{\@member{\@advisor, Supervisor}}
\setcounter{@members}{1}        
\newcounter{@minmembers}

\newcommand{\member}[1]{
  \addtocounter{@members}{1}   
  \ifcase\value{@members} 
    \typeout{Thesis format internal error.  Too few committee members.} \or
    \typeout{Thesis format internal error.  Advisor left off committee.} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberb}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberc}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberd}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@membere}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberf}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberg}{\@member{#1}} \or
    \newcommand{\@memberh}{\@member{#1}} 
  \else
    \typeout{Error using thesis format.  Too many committee members.}
  \fi
}

\newcounter{@membersprinted}


\def\maketitle{         
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small % Local definitions to make \thanks produce
    \let\footnoterule\relax % \normalsize footnotes with no separating rule.
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \null
    \parskip=0pt
    \begin{center}
      \vglue -.25in   % this makes top margin 2in
      {\Large \scshape\expandafter{\@title} \par}
      \vglue 2ex
      {\normalsize by \par}
      {\large\@author\par\par}
      \vglue 3ex
      {\normalsize Department of \@department\par}
      {\normalsize University\par}
    \end{center}
      \vglue 3ex plus 1fill
        \setcounter{@minmembers}{5} 
      \begin{center}
      \parbox{2.8in}{
        Date:\hfill\rule[-.4ex]{2.35in}{.5pt}\par
        \vspace*{0.01in}
        Approved:
        \vspace*{0.2in}
        { \centering\normalsize
          \setcounter{@membersprinted}{0}
          \loop
          \ifnum \value{@membersprinted} < \value{@members} 
            \addtocounter{@membersprinted}{1}
            \ifcase\value{@membersprinted}
              \typeout{Thesis style--internal error printing members.} \or
            \@membera \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberb \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberc \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberd \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@membere \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberf \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberg \or
            \vspace*{0.2in}
            \@memberh
            \vspace*{0.2in}            \else \typeout{Thesis style--internal error printing members.}
            \fi
          \repeat
          \loop
          \ifnum \value{@membersprinted} < \value{@minmembers}
            \addtocounter{@membersprinted}{1}
            \@member{}
          \repeat
        }
      }\hfill
      \end{center}
      \vglue 3ex plus 1fill
    \begin{center}
      {\normalsize 
            Dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment of the \par
            requirements for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy \par
          in the Department of \@department \par
          in the Graduate School of \par
          University \par
          \vglue 0.75em
          \@date \par
      }
    \end{center}
    \par\vglue 1ex\@thanks\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0} 
  \let\thanks\relax
  \let\maketitle\relax
}
```

I then generate the document itself using the following file:

```
\documentclass[PhD]{title_abstract}

\usepackage{parskip}

\author{Me}
\advisor{John Smith}
\member{John Doe}
\member{Jane Doe}
\member{John Roe}
\member{Jane Roe}

\department{Departments}
\title{A Really Great Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle{}

\end{document}
```

And in return I get the error:

```
l.18 \maketitle
               {}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
```

It generates this same error 5x on each compilation. I can't begin to discern where the required number would be and why 0 is an appropriate number to provide. If someone more knowledgeable on this could point me to how I could fix this, that would be greatly appreciated. I get the exact same set of errors when typesetting the abstract page (code not provided), but I imagine the source of the error is paralleled between them and fixing one would enable me the fix the other. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "why 0 is an appropriate number to provide"  is easy to answer, tex always adds 0 if it is missing a number, it does not mean that is a sensible value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed that was the case, I think my confusion is where should I number go in the first place? If I am able to simply provide "0" somewhere to suppress the error, that would be fine with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
 \raisebox{pt}
```

so tex sees `p` not a length, hence

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
```

It should presumably be

```
     \raisebox{1pt}
```

or whatever length you want

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for looking into this. I now have an error-free compilation and can get back to focusing on writing. Very much obliged.